# Read a Linux Disk in MacOS?

Tags: macos, unix, filesystem

I have a two-disk NAS in RAID 1 that's not cooperating. I tried taking one of the disks out and plugging it into my iMac via a USB enclosure to copy the files off of it, but MacOS can't read the disk. I assume it's probably Ext3 or Ext4, some kind of Linux format. How can I get the files off of the disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux is very flexible when it comes to filesystem formats and disk setups.

The most common problem you will encounter is the most popular filesystem for Linux: ext4, which is of course not supported by Apple under macOS.

To gain access to these filesystems, you need either 
[OSXFuse](http://osxfuse.github.io/) and a slow implementation of read-only access (eg ext4fuse, eg via macports or homebrew) or the commercial [Paragon ExtFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/de/home/extfs-mac/).

A great many more exotic filesystem setups cannnot be dealt with from within macOS.

A more convoluted but more flexible solution method might involve either booting your Mac into Linux and copy the files or using a Virtual Machine that runs Linux to extcrat the files.

Virtual Box usually can handle USB (provided the settings are right) and most Linux installations from within there as well (again: settings). The Linux installation needs support for the actual filesystem (mainstream distributions usually do.) As the RAID was 1 aka mirroring, one of the disks should then be readable.

Comment: Thanks! If I use virtual box with Ubuntu, will Ubuntu be able to mount the drive even though macOS can’t?

Comment: @At0mic: Yes, VirtualBox can do that (source: have done that).